# Determining similarity between two equations

Tags: regression, similarities

For some work I am doing, I want to determine how similar a set of linear equations are to y=x

The other linear equations are determined through linear regression of different datasets (all of which have very high R^2 values, hence wanting to compare the lines of best fit to the ideal y=x).

My first thought would be to determine the differences for both the gradient and intercept for the fitted equations against y=x, but then I am unsure how to combine these values into a single quantity.

Comment: If you do wish, you can basically take the Euclidean norm of the difference between the coefficients (as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$). As always, it is helpful to know what your goal is with such a “similarity score”

Comment: @Stephen Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.